# how to read bulletted/numbered lists using word range object?

Tags: python, windows, com, ms-word

i got range object for a selected part in word document.
i want to get the text in that range.
problem i am facing is that i want to read bulleted/numbered lists with the number/bullets.
for example,if content of selected area is,

1.abc
2.bcd
3.efg

i want to get the string read to be 1.abc 2.bcd 3.efg.

i used range.text. it gives only content of list without bullets/numbers.
i used even range.ListFormat.ListString with range.text.
Here problem is that,if selected part is

1.ab**c

2.bcd

3.efg**
then what string i get is "1. c bcd efg"  .mostly because range.ListFormat.ListString gives the bullet/number for the first list item.

but what i want is somthing like

1. c 2. bcd 3. efg

is there any way/property to do it?
preferably using word object model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with something like this, but the details depend on whether you want paragraph termination characters in there, and so on.

```
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim s As String
s = ""
For Each p In Selection.Range.Paragraphs
  s = s & p.Range.ListFormat.ListString & " " & p.Range.Text
Next
Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks.this code gave a good idea.it gives full text in a paragraph even if part of that paragraph(list) is selected.anyway this idea gave good direction to get the solution.